# What is the right way to identify client app?

Tags: rest, mobile, web, oauth, websocket

What is the right way to identify client application (mobile or js web app) which can't store API keys securely? OAuth's client_id and client_secret seems to be useless for this kind of clients.

Comment: exact, useless it is.

Answer (score 0):

http://samy.pl/evercookie/

> evercookie is a javascript API available that produces
>       extremely persistent cookies in a browser. Its goal
>       is to identify a client even after they've removed standard
>       cookies, Flash cookies (Local Shared Objects or LSOs), and
>       others.